# Edit Component on webform

Tags: css

How to change component style,there is cssclass in component edit, we don't know where to write the class. Any help please.

Comment: DO you know how to use the developer tools built into your browser?

Comment: Can you please brief on that.. we are not get in to the level.

Comment: i have noticed that custom css url in  (Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs) which did not apply styles to newly created or existing page. Any help please.

Comment: you can write that class definition and its attributes in your theme's css file. Or you can create a markup component and write CSS inside script tags in that component